# How can we use the LinqToSQL in ASP.NET MVC 2 Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone help me to write an Application using ASP.NET MVC 2 and LinqToSQL??? also explain the Repository Pattern!!!

Comment: This is way too vague and is also two different questions. If you want to learn ASP.NET MVC 2, I recommend [Pro Asp.net Mvc V2 Framework](http://apress.com/book/view/1430228865) by Steven Sanderson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specify what kind of help, it's very hard to answer your question. [This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) from Scott Gu might help you get started with linq to sql.

[Here's a link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx) to another article on the repository pattern, and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/linqrepository.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Cyril.. I got the things from that web